# I want to give each of my array element a number

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this code, a problem with is that it lists numbers for individual array elements instead of a whole array.

I did try other methods including .map but I failed.

let names = 'Bilbo, Gandalf, Nazgul, Bob, Grim, Laniakea, Dzevid, Levan, George, What';

```
let arr = names.split(', ');

for (let name of arr) {
for(let i =1; i < arr.length; i++)
  document.write( i + ` A message to ${name}.` + `<br>` ); // A message to Bilbo  (and other names)

}
```

1. My results with this code is this:

   ```
   1 A message to Bilbo.
   2 A message to Bilbo.
   3 A message to Bilbo.
   4 A message to Bilbo.
   5 A message to Bilbo.
   6 A message to Bilbo.
   7 A message to Bilbo.
   8 A message to Bilbo.
   9 A message to Bilbo.
   1 A message to Gandalf.
   2 A message to Gandalf.
   3 A message to Gandalf.
   4 A message to Gandalf.
   5 A message to Gandalf.
   6 A message to Gandalf.
   7 A message to Gandalf.
   8 A message to Gandalf.
   9 A message to Gandalf.
   1 A message to Nazgul.
   2 A message to Nazgul.
   3 A message to Nazgul.
   4 A message to Nazgul.
   5 A message to Nazgul.
   6 A message to Nazgul.
   7 A message to Nazgul.
   8 A message to Nazgul.
   9 A message to Nazgul.
   1 A message to Bob.
   2 A message to Bob.
   3 A message to Bob.
   4 A message to Bob.
   5 A message to Bob.
   6 A message to Bob.
   7 A message to Bob.
   8 A message to Bob.
   9 A message to Bob.
   1 A message to Grim.
   2 A message to Grim.
   3 A message to Grim.
   4 A message to Grim.
   5 A message to Grim.
   6 A message to Grim.
   7 A message to Grim.
   8 A message to Grim.
   9 A message to Grim.
   1 A message to Laniakea.
   2 A message to Laniakea.
   3 A message to Laniakea.
   4 A message to Laniakea.
   5 A message to Laniakea.
   6 A message to Laniakea.
   7 A message to Laniakea.
   8 A message to Laniakea.
   9 A message to Laniakea.
   1 A message to Dzevid.
   2 A message to Dzevid.
   3 A message to Dzevid.
   4 A message to Dzevid.
   5 A message to Dzevid.
   6 A message to Dzevid.
   7 A message to Dzevid.
   8 A message to Dzevid.
   9 A message to Dzevid.
   1 A message to Levan.
   2 A message to Levan.
   3 A message to Levan.
   4 A message to Levan.
   5 A message to Levan.
   6 A message to Levan.
   7 A message to Levan.
   8 A message to Levan.
   9 A message to Levan.
   1 A message to George.
   2 A message to George.
   3 A message to George.
   4 A message to George.
   5 A message to George.
   6 A message to George.
   7 A message to George.
   8 A message to George.
   9 A message to George.
   1 A message to What.
   2 A message to What.
   3 A message to What.
   4 A message to What.
   5 A message to What.
   6 A message to What.
   7 A message to What.
   8 A message to What.
   9 A message to What.
   ```

I want it to work in the following way:

```
    1 A message to Bilbo
    2 A message to Gandalf
    3 A message to Nazgul
    4 A message to Bob
    5 A message to Grim
    6 A message to Laniakea
    7 A message to Dzevid
    8 A message to Levan
    9 A message to George
    10 A message to what
```

Comment: You don't need to use 2 for loops then, just 1 will do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you use a second loop ?
just set a counter like

```
let names = 'Bilbo, Gandalf, Nazgul, Bob, Grim, Laniakea, Dzevid, Levan, George, What';

let arr = names.split(', ');
let count = 1;
for (let name of arr) {
 document.write( count + ` A message to ${name}.` + `<br>` );
 count++;
}
```

Or

```
for (i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) { 
    document.write( i + ` A message to ${name}.` + `<br>` );
}
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly well for my particular project, thank you :)

Comment: @laniakea If you feel that this user has answered your question, you can mark it as the correct answer by selecting the grey tick mark next to the question. This also helps other people with similar issues to identify the correct answer which might help them solve their issue.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve. But here is the code which can help.

```
let names = 'Bilbo, Gandalf, Nazgul, Bob, Grim, Laniakea, Dzevid, Levan, George, What';\
names = names.split(',');

names.forEach((name, index) => {
    document.write(`${index} A message to ${name.trim()}`);
})
```

In this example we firstly transform that long string into array of names.
Then using simple `forEach` handle each name. Note that I use `name.trim()` for removing unnecessary spaces left after splitting.

Answer (score 2):

Actually there was no need to add `for (let name of arr) { .... }`. You can just remove that line. Other than that, you need to start for loop from `i = 0`, as an array starts from `index 0`,

```
let names = 'Bilbo, Gandalf, Nazgul, Bob, Grim, Laniakea, Dzevid, Levan, George, What';
let arr = names.split(', '); 

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  document.write( `${i+1}`  + ` A message to ${arr[i]}.` + `<br>` );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the map for looping and you do not need second loop because `arr` is one-dimensional array

```js
let names = 'Bilbo, Gandalf, Nazgul, Bob, Grim, Laniakea, Dzevid, Levan, George, What';

let arr = names.split(', ');



arr.map((d, i)=>{
  document.write( i+1 + ` A message to ${d}.` + `<br>` ); // A message to Bilbo  (and other names)
})
```